# cURL works i terminal -- error in PHP

Tags: php, curl, terminal, box-api

I looked through all of the other terminal vs. PHP questions and couldn't find a solve.

I'm working with BOX API and this works to retrieve a list of files in a folder:

```
curl https://api.box.com/2.0/folders/0 \
-H "Authorization: Bearer EdbmVAlajxC0VrkZoYA0wgPjSdNFQSeO"
```

But this does not work:

```
$postURL="https://api.box.com/2.0/folders/0";

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $postURL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Authorization: Bearer EdbmVAlajxC0VrkZoYA0wgPjSdNFQSeO'));

$data = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);
```

What am I missing in the translation?

Comment: What do you get from `curl_error($ch)`?

Comment: Hi Dave -- looks like Nick's answer solved the problem, so it would be appropriate to accept it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your results.  It looks like your first attempt using the `curl` command is using the `GET` method.  I enabled `--trace-ascii` on your curl request as such:

```
curl --trace-ascii test.txt https://api.box.com/2.0/folders/0 \
-H "Authorization: Bearer EdbmVAlajxC0VrkZoYA0wgPjSdNFQSeO"
```

The contents of test.txt show that a `GET` request is being made.

Your PHP script is using the `POST` method.  When I changed `CURLOPT_POST` to `false`, the PHP script worked for me as well.  It looks like the server is expecting a `GET` request instead of a `POST` request.

Comment: Rock the house.  Thanks for the quick, perfect answer!  Nick Coons for Congress!